# How to save particular lines from a dat file

Tags: sed

I have a file containing 10000 lines. I want to save data on particular lines. like line 205, 408 .. etc.

```
sed -n "205,408,611,814,1017,1220,1423,1626,1829,2032,2235,2438,2641,2844,3047,3250,3453,3656,3859,4062,4265,4468,4671,4874,5077,5280,5483,5686,5889,6092,6295p' evecs.dat > ext.dat
```

It shows an error :
sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unknown command: `,'

Comment: You start the string with `"` and end with "'", typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TO print only the 2nd and 4th line:

```
sed -n '2p;4p' file
```

Since you have many lines:

1. Prepare a file with all the line numbers, say here we want 2nd and 4th:

   ```
   $ cat line
   2
   4
   ```
2. Prepare a string for the sed print command :

   ```
   $ x=$(sed 's/$/p/' line | paste -sd";")
   $ echo $x
   2p;4p
   ```
3. Print those lines from the original file:

   ```
   $ sed -n "$x" file
   ```